# Why linux ip command output is so messy

Tags: linux, ip, ifconfig

I understand that the ifconfig command has not been developed and updated for a while and is now deprecated, we are supposed to use the ip command. I just dont understand why in 2020 the output has to be so difficult to read. Why they have not yet added a --pretty version.
I know this is not a technical question but I just dont get it. Im a nooby trying to study network and I am reading the output from 'route -n' so I can understand what they mean in 'ip route'

Answer (score 6):

You can color the output

`ip -c`

it makes it a bit easier and faster to read what you want

for me, I use an alias for that in ~/.bashrc

`alias ip='ip -c'`

Answer (score 3):

If you want pretty - and tons of information, to boot - take a look at **nmcli** (part of the NetworkManager package): https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html.

A simple command like `nmcli device show` gives you more info than `ip` or `ifconfig`, and in a nice, tabular format.

Comment: `nmcli` does not get you the same info. And `nmcli` only works where NetworkManager is installed (which excludes 99% of Linux systems where `ip` does work).

Comment: 99%??? Just a bit of any exaggeration, don't you think? I've installed 20+ distros over the past 2 years and all of them came with NetworkManager installed by default.

Comment: `ip` works on all Android devices (which are in the billions), routers, cameras, etc. And of course, on all Linux servers and desktops where NetworkManager may or may not run.

Comment: That's correct. But since the OP stated "Linux" in the question, I wasn't considering Android at all. I was just trying to give him/her an alternative - I don't like the `ip` command either.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think ip route is overly hard.

```
$ ip route
```

default via 100.115.92.193 dev eth0
100.115.92.192/28 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 100.115.92.202

Fairly easy to make it prettier for yourself

```
echo "IP Address is";ip route |cut -d " " -f 9
```

IP Address is

100.115.92.202

Or any variation using grep, sed, awk or cut, Obviously you will have to play around to suit your taste as well, as well make the output work for your system.